# How can I use "find selection" in mathematica?

Tags: editing

I want to use `find selection` functionality in Mathematica and I found some articles saying it could be accessed by `Ctrl + E`. However, nothing happens when I try `Ctrl + E`. The normal `find` by `Ctrl + F` does work.
I searched for a while, but I couldn't find the solution, for everyone does not seem to have the problem as such.
How can I use `find selection` in Mathematica?

I use Mathematica version 12.0.0 and Windows 10.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: `Ctrl-E` to pick, `F3` (on Windows - use whatever equivalent for your environment) to successively find that pick.

Comment: Select something, then `Ctrl-E` adds your selection to the `Find` dialog box.  You won't see results until you open the `Find` dialog with either the menu or `Ctrl-F`.  `F3` works also.

Comment: Thank you. So, what `Ctrl-E` does is just shortcut of copying and pasting to the Find dialog, right? If that so, it is not the case I'm wanting. What I want is the way to find a word only from the selected area, the one common programming IDEs are equipped with. Does Mathematica also have the functionality like this?